# Grails Gorm Disable Sorting for a Field in Scaffolding

Tags: sorting, grails, grails-orm

I am looking for an easy way to disable the sorting link for just one column in a gorm model using scaffolding, but have not found anything to this regard.

something like

```
static constraints = {
    entryDate(nullable: false, blank: false, sortable: false)
}
```

is this possible in gorm?

Comment: are you generating your views using scaffolding?  if they are static (meaning generating actual files), you can just remove the hyper link. but if they are at run-time not sure if there is an easy way, but probably you can customize your templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own attributes and customize the scaffolding-templates.

Custom attributes:

```
static constraints = {
    entryDate(nullable: false, blank: false, attributes: [sortable: false])
}
```

Customizing the scaffolding-template could look like this:

```
props.eachWithIndex { p, i ->
cp = domainClass.constrainedProperties[p.name]
if (p.isAssociation() || (cp.attributes?.sortable != null && !cp.attributes.sortable) ) { %>
```